# Using sed with the EDITOR variable in a script for virsh or sudoers

Tags: bash, sed

**Long story short, I need the command below to work in a bash script.**

I need to change the network subnet which a virtual kvm is using. What makes this hard for me is trying to get it to change as a command. Normally you run the command sudo **virsh net-edit default** and it opens a vi (or whatever) session and you edit and close.

**net-edit** Option allows the user to edit the XML configuration of a virtual network, using their preferred editor.  net-edit launches the command (or script) is defined in the users $EDITOR environment variable, passing it a temporary copy of the XML configuration for the virtual network.

When the user exits the editor, net-edit checks if the temporary file was changed.

So for me, I want to pass this through sed so I can use it in a script.  The following example would work from the command line, but it will not work for me in a script. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I have not figured this out yet. If anyone has an ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

This works from the command line, but not in a script. Get error messages about the command :

```
    EDITOR='sed -i "s/192.168.100.1/192.168.11.1/g"' virsh net-edit default
```

This is a related thread:
[Changing the dhcp IP range in Virbr0's XML file using virsh in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365391/changing-the-dhcp-ip-range-in-virbr0s-xml-file-using-virsh-in-bash-script)

This is the error message

./test: line 2: export: `net-edit': not a valid identifier

Comment: The specific error message you're getting could give a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: it's a standard script error probably with exporting or something.  "line 62: export: `net-edit': not a valid identifier"

Comment: Did you add `export` in front of the command you posted? If so, don't.

Comment: I am a tool, I find my issue with the way I was issuing the sed command, and I wasn't running it as root. It has been a long week, thanks for responding though, much appreciated. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with the sed command in a couple of ways and at one point I forgot to run it with root authority so in short, the command above WILL work in a script.