# Replace $EDITOR with sed or custom script

Tags: bash, vim, sed, editor, environment-variables

I need to replace `$EDITOR` with sed. An example can be seen here:
[Changing the dhcp IP range in Virbr0's XML file using virsh in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365391/changing-the-dhcp-ip-range-in-virbr0s-xml-file-using-virsh-in-bash-script)

I would like to open Vim after after something is modified using sed, to allow users to review text and add modifications. How would I do such a thing?

I tried this, but obviously it does not work for me.

```
EDITOR='vim - sed -i s/foo/bar/g' virsh net-edit default
```

Also, I tried to replace sed by custom script which opens temp file. Then, after modifications I tried to open vim with that temp file but I got:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

How can I accomplish such task?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script for it:

```
cp $1 /tmp/tempfile
sed 's/foo/bar/g' < /tmp/tempfile > $1
vim $1
```

Then set that script as editor command.

Another solution is to use the commands in vim, which are very sed like.

```
EDITOR="vim -c %s/foo/bar/g"
```

should do want you want, too.

Comment: If you specifically want to use sed first, you can pipe into vim such as: `sed 's/foo/bar/g' < file | vim -`.

Comment: You could, but you can't place that in $EDITOR.

Comment: I implemented such script but without vim. Everything works fine but I NEED vim there. With vim I got: Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal... Everything implemented is in python...

Comment: Your another solution is very interesting!  But I would  like to figure out how I could fix my situation... Will see... If I'll not find solution then will use your second solution and will accept answer.

Comment: Aha! Should have mentioned python in the question! I have python scripts that call vim. They do it like this: `subprocess.call('vim -c \'{0}\' {1}'.format(vimCommand, filePath)
, shell=True)`. The important part is the `shell=True`!

Comment: The problem is that I need output, the result of call. So subprocess.call is not  suitable for me :-(

Comment: While subprocess.call may not be exactly suitable for you, since you need to be able to read in the output of the call, I'd suggest reading the docs for the Subprocess module. There are methods that allow you to do what David's suggesting while still reading in STDOUT/ERR.